# Scripts won't affect clones

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine, swap, unityscript

I made a script which swaps two game objects on click.But the script won't work because the objects are actualy clones of the original prefab.

This is the script(java) :

```
#pragma strict

var object1 : GameObject;
var object2 : GameObject;
function OnMouseDown ()
{

Instantiate(object2,object1.transform.position,object1.transform.rotation);

Destroy(object1);
}
```

I use this script to create other game objects (clones)[c#] :

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] obj;
public float spawnMin = 1f;
public float spawnMax = 2f;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Spawn ();
}

void Spawn() 
{
    Instantiate(obj[Random.Range(0, obj.GetLength(0))],transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                    Invoke ("Spawn", Random.Range (spawnMin, spawnMax));
                    }

}
```

The objects get renamed to *NAME* (Clone).

What I wanna do is make the script affect clones too.So they will swap when I click on them.

Comment: ... "script(java)" is Java? if so, TAG the language, if not, TAG the language.

Comment: I would but I have no idea how to do it...

Comment: You added `object`, `unity`, and `swap` tags... language should also be included in the same place. Just edit your question to be able to add to the tags.

Comment: Oh,you mean those tags.Done.

Comment: That doesn't look like java

Comment: The first script is a javascript